# Show/Hide parameter Jenkins with Jquery

Tags: jenkins

My Jquery script expects to show "NAME" parameter if "TRIGGER_DISPLAY" parameter is checked and vice versa.

But it didn't work as my expectation. Any suggestion on how can I fix it?

I used JQuery Jenkins plugin 1.12.4-1.

```
Q(function() {
    Q("div.parameters").find("input[value='TRIGGER_DISPLAY'] + input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
        if (Q("div.parameters").find("input[value='TRIGGER_DISPLAY']").next().prop('checked')) {
            Q("div.parameters").find("input[value='NAME']").parentsUntil('div.parameters').show();
        } else {
            Q("div.parameters").find("input[value='NAME']").parentsUntil('div.parameters').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

[image]